# iPhone: how to send image data to server using JSON?

Tags: iphone, image, json, send

I am newbie iphone developer, I am using JSON to send and retrieve data from server. But I used to work with text between iPhone and server. Now I would like to send image data from iPhone to server and vice versa, retrieve image data from server database to iphone. Can anyone show me how I can accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Encode your image with base64, then send the base64 string as json. On the serverside decode the base64 again and save it or do whatever you want with it

Comment: And first compress it as JPEG or PNG data to get good performance.